# TypeScript: implicitly type 'any' because of no type annotation and direct or indirect reference in its own initializer

Tags: reactjs, typescript

With the following code snippet I'm getting the following error: 
`TypeScript error: 'route' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.  TS7022`

```js
const store = configureStore()

const renderWithRouter = (
  ui: any,
  {
    route = '/', /* ERROR HERE */
    history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] }),
  } = {},
) => {
  return {
    ...render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>{ui}</Router>
      </Provider>,
    ),
    history,
  }
}

export default renderWithRouter
```

I was working in a completely section of the code and had to upgrade a package, and then all of a sudden this started complaining. (The packages were `react-router-dom` and `@types/react-router-dom`).

I'm not exactly sure how to get past this, and furthermore I'm a little confused by what's going on with the second parameter in the function. it looks like they were trying to identify a default empty parameter, however they've filled in values on the left hand side for `route` and `history`.

edit:
I have resolved the issue by adding the following:

```js
interface IRenderParams {
  route: string | undefined;
  history: MemoryHistory<any>
}
...
{
    route = '/', /* ERROR HERE */
    history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] }),
  } = {} as IRenderParams
...
```

This resolves the issue, however, I still am not sure exactly why is this defined like this.

Comment: Try to add explicit `any` type where variable is initiated. This is a work around. you should probably install type packages.

Comment: What type do expect `createMemoryHistory` in its parameter?

Comment: Instead of writing `route: string | undefined` you can write `route?: string`

Comment: I've seen this error when I have **circular references** between types/functions in some cases. In my case, I had 2 drizzle tables, 1 referencing the other, and that's not a good idea. Tables shouldn't reference each other. Removing that fixed it.